# Extracting part from a file column

Tags: text-processing, columns

I want to extract part from a log file column which is like this:

```
xx.xxx.xx.xx#59796:
```

Edit:

This is the actual log line:

```
Jan 10 17:38:11 server named[747]: client 21x.x0.x8x.xxx#40649: view external: query (cache) 'domain.TLD/A/IN' denied
```

The part before the "#" in the line above is an IP address, and I want to extract only the IP. The part after the "#" is random numbers and not always the same.

I use the below command to grep a pattern, extract the IP column, and then redirect the output to text file, but then I have to use an editor to leave out the extra characters from the extracted column.

```
grep -E 'view external.*denied' /var/log/messages |awk '{print $7}' > view_external_denied_ip.txt
```

If I can extract only the IP without the extra characters in the column, I would use the sort command to sort them ( sort | uniq -c | sort -rn ).

Comment: Please show us some of the actual input, we can't help you find it if we don't know what the rest of the line looks like.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this. Most trivial would be `cut -d# -f1` but you can probably get something quicker by handling the whole line at once (e.g., with perl or awk). I second the request for an example line.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the log line.

Comment: Yes derobert the cut command helped too, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give a better answer if you show your actual input but if all you need is to remove the characters after `#` (inclusive), use any of these (assuming your lines only contain a single `#`):

```
awk '/view external.*denied/{print $7}' logfile | sed 's/#.*//'
```

or

```
awk '/view external.*denied/{print $7}' logfile | cut -d '#' -f 1
```

Comment: `awk '/view external.*denied/{print $7}' /var/log/messages | sed 's/#.*//' |sort |uniq -c |sort -rn`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single sed command. First, as a matter of general strategy, to extract a part of a line in sed, use the `s` command, with a regex that matches the whole line (starting with `^` and ending with `$`), with the part to retain in a group (`\(…\)`), replacing the whole line by the content of the group(s) to keep. Pass the `-n` option to turn off default printing and put the `p` modifier to print lines where there is something to extract. You can restrict the extraction further by prefixing the command with a regex that must match the line.

```
sed -n '/view external.*denied/ s/^.* client \([0-9.][0-9.]*\)#.*/\1/p'
```

If you prefer to use awk, you can use its `sub` function to remove a part of a string.

```
grep -E 'view external.*denied' /var/log/messages |
awk '{sub(/#.*/, "", $7); print $7}'
```

You can also use the `index` function to locate the `#` and the `substr` function to extract the part you want to keep.

```
grep -E 'view external.*denied' /var/log/messages |
awk '{print substr($7, 1, index($7, "#"))}'
```

You can easily combine the grep command into the awk command.

```
</var/log/messages awk '/view external.*denied/ {sub(/#.*/, "", $7); print $7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\#.*$'//' /path/to/logfile # this will trim anything including and after a `#` on every line.
```

Comment: Maybe you could expand this a bit and explain what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you, but I had to adjust the sed command to make it work, like terdon did.